# subprocess fails to call a function

Tags: python-3.x, subprocess

I am trying to call a function using `subprocess.Popen` as:

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(["/usr/local/bin/qstat", "-u", "rudrab"],stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
  numjobs = proc.stdout.read()
```

which is giving error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "genpos.py", line 159, in <module>
    proc = subprocess.Popen(["/usr/local/bin/qstat", "-u", "rudrab"],stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
  File "/opt/python-3.5/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 950, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "/opt/python-3.5/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 1544, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/local/bin/qstat'
```

but `qstat` is in my path:

```
 which qstat
/usr/local/bin/qstat
```

what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: what is the output of `$ ls -al /usr/local/bin/qstat`? (is the file really there? is it executable?

Comment: ` ls -al /usr/local/bin/qstat
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 203K May 13  2016 /usr/local/bin/qstat`

yes it is, and its also inside path, so, just qsub gives me the output